# Split on comma except when the comma is between two numbers

Tags: java, regex

Consider the following string.

`String s = "va1, var2, aVar,var4, my_var55 DECIMAL(20,4)"`

I was earlier using just `.split(",")` to get the variable tokens without taking into the consideration the `DECIMAL(20,4)`. The regex should be somewhat like this that if comma occurs b/w two numbers then it shouldn't split. What regex to use in `split()` so that I can get the following result:

`["var1", "var2", "aVar", "var4", "my_var55 DECIMAL(20,4)"]`

P.S Note that a variale can end with a number but cannot start with it.

Comment: Use `(?<!\d),(?!\d)\\h*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
(?<=\S),(?!\h*\d)\h*
```

- `(?<=\S)` Assert a non whitespace char before the comma
- `(?!\h*\d)`  Assert no optional horizontal whitespace chars followed by a digit
- `\h*` Match 0+ horizontal whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2WzcTq/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/rGPSye)

```
String s = "va1, var2, aVar,var4, my_var55 DECIMAL(20,4)";
for (String element : s.split("(?<=\\S),(?!\\h*\\d)\\h*"))
    System.out.println(element);
```

Output

```
va1
var2
aVar
var4
my_var55 DECIMAL(20,4)
```

To not split on a comma at the end of the string, you could also assert that the comma is followed by a word char except a digit

```
(?<=\S),(?=\h*\b[^\W\d])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZH4zXf/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
String[] result = s.split(",(?!\\d)\\s*");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gquKIk/1)

**Details**

- `,` - a comma
- `(?!\d)` - not immediately followed with a digit
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/h2i4Bw):

```java
String s = "va1, var2, aVar,var4, my_var55 DECIMAL(20,4)";
String[] result = s.split(",(?!\\d)\\s*");
for (String x: result) {
    System.out.println(x); 
}
```

Output:

```
va1
var2
aVar
var4
my_var55 DECIMAL(20,4)
```